# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://writing.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious -- how many people voted? (How many were eligible?)  Were other recently ex-beta sites also having elections around this time, and if so, how active were theirs?  Any other interesting details to share?

Comment: The data file that will be posted at the end of the election will answer the number of voters.  Everyone with at least 150 rep is eligible, so you could count that by figuring out how many pages down in the user list that rep level is and then multiplying by page size.  I think there's enough data in SEDE (Stack Exchange Data Explorer) to answer that question for elections in general; if you ask on Meta.SE I'll bet somebody could write that query.

Comment: About 1800 were eligible (yeah, I did the count a couple days ago).  So just over 10% of eligible voters voted (199), which is pretty high considering a lot of people haven't logged in for months or years.  This trick only works once but I knew how many voters there were from looking here: https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/80?page=1

Comment: @Cyn It also says in the online summary of the vote tallies: "Cyn is the winner after counting 199 ballots using Meek STV. "  So you should be able to find out on future elections too.

Comment: @Troyen For sure, but the badge trick showed me the number of people who had voted to date, before the election closed.  Including their names and the day and time they voted.  Obviously it never shows *who* they voted for.